# How to extract the last element out of an invalid json string with js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm using a nodejs speech recognition API that returns a string with multiple texts inside a JSON like structure which is invalid and unusable

```
{
  "text": "Play"
}
{
  "text": "Play astronaut"
}
{
  "text": "Play astronaut in the"
}
{
  "text": "Play astronaut in the ocean"
}
{
  "entities": {},
  "intents": [],
  "text": "Play astronaut in the ocean.",
  "traits": {}
}
```

and I only want last element which is

```
{
  "entities": {},
  "intents": [],
  "text": "Play astronaut in the ocean.",
  "traits": {}
}
```

by filtering it out or something
to extract the text "Play astronaut in the ocean."

The API always outputs multiple text elements in different quantities each time, but I want the last element is that possible? or should I find a different API that's usable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the response is returned as an array, ie [{
"text": "Play"
}, { next one.. }] etc

Then you can get the last element in the array by variablising the array, get its length, and find the last object.

e.g.

```
const x = [{ text.. }, { text.. }]
const lastItem = x[x.length - 1]
```

Then if you also want to find the last item *within* that object, you could also do that with `Object.values`

```
const lastItemObject = Object.values(lastItem)
const lastItemInTheObject = lastItemObject[lastItemObject.length - 1]
```

Comment: The response is returned as an array but without commas separating each item

Comment: Perhaps try the above solution, it may just be how it is formatted on your side. If that does not work, can you check the `typeof` the object that is returned that groups the various `{ .. }` objects?
Also if you have the link to the API docs, that will also help me understand what response type should be coming back